# AgConnect Performance Monitoring - Version Conflict

Tags: android, dependencies, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

With a `build.gradle` like this (simplified):

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1"
        classpath "com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.7.3.302"
    }
}
```

Module `build.gradle` (merely alike the [Enabling APM](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/appgallery-connect-guides/agc-apm-android-getstarted-0000001052887262#section640224332214) tutorial):

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "com.huawei.agconnect"
}

agcp {
    enableAPMS true
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.huawei.hms:base:6.7.0.300"
    implementation "com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.7.3.302"
    implementation "com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms:1.6.1.303"
}
```

I get this warning:

> --W- [`APMSClassVisitor`] `agconnect-apms` version [`1.6.1.303`] is not same with `agconnect-apms-plugin` version [`1.5.2.310`], please update one of them, or invalidate AndroidStudio cache if these versions have been same.

Followed by further problems:

```
[Instrument] an error occurred while instrumenting an unknown class, skipping it: Module requires ASM6
[Instrument] an error occurred while instrumenting an unknown class, skipping it: NestHost requires ASM7
[Instrument] an error occurred while instrumenting an unknown class, skipping it: NestMember requires ASM7
```

How to upgrade the (bundled) `agconnect-apms-plugin` version to `1.6.1.303`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the versions match, one has to add `agconnect-apms-plugin` version `1.6.1.300`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext {
        agp_version = '7.3.1'
        hms_version = '6.7.0.300'
        agc_version = '1.7.3.302'
        apms_version = '1.6.1.300'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
        classpath "com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:$agc_version"
        classpath "com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:$apms_version"

    }
}
```

And disable the integrated `agconnect-apms-plugin` `1.5.2.310`, which is otherwise being preferred:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "com.huawei.agconnect"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.huawei.hms:base:$hms_version"
    implementation "com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:$agc_version"
    implementation "com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms:$apms_version"
}
```

---

Note: `enableAPMS` `false` is the default value; `true` is what caused the version conflict.